# How to convert request.data to dict?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I try to get JSON data from client using this line (requests library) POST request:

```
request.data
```

How to convert this to dict?

It works:

```
response_data = request.get_json()
```

But how convert this to dict?

Comment: Try `request.json()`, assuming that request is the name of the response...

Comment: Can you please provide some details what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you response text is json use dict_data = json.loads(json_str)

Comment: I tried this: ` response_data = request.json()
        print(response_data)` and got:  ` object is not callable"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Edit: For post request:

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"

payload = {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 901,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
 }
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "c71c65a6-07f4-a2a4-a6f8-dca3fd706a7a"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(type(response.json()))
```

> class 'dict'

---

You can use something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random"

headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "77047c8b-caed-2b2c-ab33-dbddf52a7a9f"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(type(response.json()))
```

> class 'dict'

Comment: I send POST request

Comment: For the post request you can use `json=` rather then `data=`. This allows you to pass a python dict straight into the post request without using json.dumps. Also you don't have to pass the content type in the header.

Answer (score 9):

```
import json

response_data = json.loads(response.text)
result = response_data.get('result')
```

you need to deserialize `response.text` to have it as dict and then user `.get` with respective key. `result` is a key in above example. and `response` was the response of a url call.

Comment: `object has no attribute 'text'"`

Comment: is your request something like this? `response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)`

Comment: No I use Flask, and POST method

Comment: I have endpoint where I need to get POST data from client: `@app.route('/protocol/<token>', methods=['POST'])`

Comment: `data = request.json['key']` where key is your key.

Comment: I need to get dict from whole json. It is nested dict

Comment: I tried this: `response_data = request.get_json().to_dict()`

Comment: Also such:  `response_data = request.get_json()` `json.loads(response_data)` the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'"

Comment: try this. `data = request.json`   `request.json` is a dict.

Comment: @Amely did it solve your problem?