# converting bytes from request.data which contains "\xbf " in content to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask

hi i am new to Flask and Flask API,

i have api end point as below :

```
@app.route('/api/createjob/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    data = request.data
```

incoming request is POST with content-type of JSON :

```
{
    "requestMap": {
        "Req": "No",
        "jobRole": "Software Engineer",
        "minWorkExp": "3 yrs",
        "maxWorkExp": "6 yrs",
        "jobDescription": "Sap SD\\nSAP SD Offshore - Hyderabad Job Description: \\n\\u2022 Should have minimum 6-7 yrs of experience in SAP SD and GTS, LE-Delivery with E2E implementation and support experience. \\u2022 Must be well conversant in working on Incident, Problem, Change Management and Release Management processes and exposure to Remedy/HPSM tool would be added advantage. \\n\\u2022 Willing to work in shifts and Handle support incidents and change requests. \\n\\u2022 Should be flexible in working with onsite and offshore teams. \\u2022 Should have handled L2 support in support engagements. \xbf Solving Direct Action Incidents: \\n\\u2022\\tanswering all SUs questions regarding operations of the system \\n\\u2022\\t Maintenance of soft configurations table entries\\n\\u2022\\ttroubleshooting of blocked interfaces \\n\\u2022\\t Analysis and proposal of solutions or workarounds for all raised issues\\n\\u2022\\t Contacting SAP OSS for clarification of the issue \\n\\u2022\\tRequesting creation or change of background jobs \\n\\u2022\\tSolving Bug Fixing Incidents:\\n\\u2022\\tFixing bugs in the customizing and configuration \\n\\u2022\\tCoordinating bug fixing in custom code with developers\\n\\u2022\\tCoordination of bug fixes concerning authorization issues with Authorization team\\n\\u2022\\tTest the bug-fixing done by Tech team (screening, functional and formal approval tests) \\n\\u2022\\tContacting SAP OSS for solving of the issue in SAP standard"

    }
}
```

content contains **\xbf** inside one of the values of the key.

i tried data.decode('utf-8')

so that i could later convert it to dict or JSON, it gives an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 1104: invalid start byte
```

i tried looking into this question but didn't help me.

[How to convert request.data to dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934100/how-to-convert-request-data-to-dict)

please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't it be \\xbf?

Comment: @Adithya thank you for your time, i have solved it.