# How can I fetch specific information for a dictionary thats in an api

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am writing a code that can give me certain information. The url https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/28472387/ranked?api_key=MY_API_KEY

provides information about my profile. When print it in text I get

```
{
    "name": "Twitter: ufrz_",
    "brawlhalla_id": 28472387,
    "rating": 2093,
    "peak_rating": 2110,
    "tier": "Diamond",
    "wins": 140,
    "games": 257,
    "region": "US-E",
    "global_rank": 0,
    "region_rank": 0,
    "legends": [
        {
            "legend_id": 3,
            "legend_name_key": "bodvar",
            "rating": 870,
            "peak_rating": 870,
            "tier": "Tin 4",
            "wins": 2,
            "games": 4
        },
        {
            "legend_id": 4,
            "legend_name_key": "cassidy",
            "rating": 968,
            "peak_rating": 968,
            "tier": "Bronze 2",
            "wins": 0,
            "games": 0
        },
        {
            "legend_id": 5,
            "legend_name_key": "orion",
            "rating": 1131,
            "peak_rating": 1131,
            "tier": "Silver 1",
            "wins": 1,
            "games": 3
        },
```

(not the full page.)

Here is the code I used to fetch this

```
import requests

url = "https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/28472387/ranked?api_key= MY_API_KEY"


r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

Now for example how would I go about fetching my rating and not the actual word but the number "2093" I tried someway but they didn't work. I am using bs4 and request and new to both so I really don't know how I would get this.

(Just want to say sorry for poorly worded question I don't really know how word my issue so my apologies in advance)

Comment: You need to show the code you wrote to try getting that value. This request is returning a JSON object. You're likely not converting that object into a Python dictionary.

Comment: I provided the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert request.data to dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934100/how-to-convert-request-data-to-dict)

Comment: Try `data = r.json()`. If that works, you have a dictionary and can address as in `data["name"]`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks tdelaney appreciate the help!

Comment: @tdelaney I have one more question how would I go about getting the ranking for the legend_key_name "bodvar" how could I specifically get that legends ranking.

Comment: `for legend in data["legends"]: print(legend["legend_key_name"])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to convert your result to a json object:

```
data = r.json()
```

Then, you can request using `data['rating']`

For your question :

> how would I go about getting the ranking for the legend_key_name "bodvar" how could I specifically get that legends ranking.

```
for legend in data['legends']:
    if legend['legend_name_key'] == "bovdar"
        print(legend['rating'])
        return legend['rating']
```

or using a function :

```
def getLegendByName(data, legendName):
    for legend in data['legends']:
        if legend['legend_name_key'] == legendName:
            return legend

    return None

legendName = "bodvar"            
data = r.json()
legend = getLegendByName(data, legendName)
if legend is not None:
    legendRating = legend['rating']
else
    print("There is no legend that exists with this name"
```

Comment: when I try doing it by a function it tells me "legendName" is not defined. When I try it the other way it says return can only be used in a function, when I removed the return statement and keep the print statement and run it, it just prints nothing.

Comment: You have to define your legendName : legendName = "bovdar", I upadated my post

Comment: It raises another error "legendRating = legend['rating']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: It is because I writed "Bovdar" and not "Bodvar", I updated : You have to return None if legend is not found